# Hardhat testing emitted events through a proxy

Tags: solidity, hardhat, openzeppelin, proxy-contracts

Have a proxy contract and the implementation contract setup and working well from manual testing using the OZ `TransparentUpgradeableProxy`.

Before using a proxy we had a single contract that wasn't upgradeable and testing emitted events was simply done by parsing the tx receipt like the following .

```
it('Should succeed and emit \'MemberRemoved\' events if admin removes a member', async function () {
      const receipt = await (await leagues.connect(admin1).removeMembers([member2.address])).wait();
      const event = receipt!.events!.find((e: any) => e.event === 'MemberRemoved');
      const user = event!.args!.user; // <-- error is here
      const leagueId = event!.args!.leagueId;
      expect(user).to.be.eq(member2.address);
      expect(leagueId1).to.be.eq(leagueId);
 });
```

That worked fine until we placed the implementation contract behind a proxy.
Now when trying to extract the event I get the error

```
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'args' of undefined
```

The only thing that is partially working is using

```
      await expect(leagues.connect(admin1).removeMembers([member2.address])).
        to.emit(leagues, 'MemberRemoved');
```

But the issue there is we can't check the arguments emitted in the event, and using `withArgs` isn't working

Comment: Had the same issue, but nothing I tried helped